# substraction mysql vb net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

this query below is used to insert data into database

```
msql = "update tb_temp set qty = qty + '" & Trim(txtStock.Text) & "' where product_id='" & Trim(cbProductID.Text) & "' "
```

it worked fine and run the addition function like it should be

but when i change the arithmetic operator into   **-**   substraction

```
msql = "update tb_temp set qty = qty - '" & Trim(txtStock.Text) & "' where product_id='" & Trim(cbProductID.Text) & "' "
```

it return unchandled exception like this

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

can someone explain this? thanks before

Comment: you should use option strict...always.  `qty = qty - '" & Trim(txtStock.Text) ` is doing math on a mumeric with a string (text).

Comment: can you give me an example? where should i use option strict? inside my connection string?

Comment: i've already fixed it.. thanks so much plutonix.. it turned out that i don't need extra single quote..hahaha

Answer (score 0):

fixed it by myself.. it turned out that i used too much single quote :)

BEFORE

```
msql = "update tb_temp set qty = qty - '" & Trim(txtStock.Text) & "' where product_id='" & Trim(cbProductID.Text) & "' "
```

AFTER

```
msql = "update tb_temp set qty = qty - " & Trim(txtStock.Text) & " where product_id='" & Trim(cbProductID.Text) & "' "
```

i remove the single quote before `" &` and it worked!